# HTML5 audio: How to check if playbackRate is supported?

Tags: html, audio

What is the correct (or does it exist?) way to check HTML5 audio: How to check if playbackRate on audio element is supported?

Some mobile browsers allow to set playbackRate and even fire ratechange but actually paying rate does not change.

Maybe some one came across such problem and found cross-platform solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `playbackRate` is recognized:

```
'playbackRate' in document.createElement('audio');
```

According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manipulating_media/HTML5_playbackRate_explained) the attribute is not supported in:

- Mobile Chrome (Android)
- IE Mobile
- Opera Mobile

Comment: This is not working at all, at least in Chrome mobile. The audio / video object has a `playbackRate` property but changing it has no effect.